# How subtraction of two float values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, subtraction

I have an issue with the subtraction of two values. when I set discount_amt value to 2.5 then total return me 0.5 but when discount_amt is set to 2.6 it return 0.3999999999999999 instead of 0.4 why?

```
var total        = parseFloat('3').toFixed(1);
var discount_amt = parseFloat('2.6').toFixed(1);
    total        = total - discount_amt;
    console.log(total);
```

```js
var total        = parseFloat('3').toFixed(1);
var discount_amt = parseFloat('2.6').toFixed(1);
    total        = total - discount_amt;
    console.log(total);
```

Comment: please don't parse numbers.

Comment: still having issue

Comment: please see the dupe target.

Comment: Just use `total.toFixed(1)` in order to get round of value

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: @NinaScholz just edited my question. I have a string values.

Comment: just keep the values as long as you can as number and apply `toFixed` only for displaying the value, but not for shaping values fro a new calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix it. You forget parsefloat() and tofixed()

```js
total = 3;
discount_amt = 2.6;

console.log(parseFloat(total).toFixed(1) + ' ' + parseFloat(discount_amt).toFixed(1));
total = parseFloat(total).toFixed(1) - parseFloat(discount_amt).toFixed(1);
console.log(parseFloat(total).toFixed(1));
```

Explanation why floats are handled this way: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439981/5686835) or directly to the link that answer refers to [link](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: but i already parseFloat and toFixed to the subtraction time then how could this happened?

Comment: Because you dont parsefloat and tofixed the total. But you should only use toFixed on your answer, because using it before wont help the accuracy of your function

Comment: ok but i don't know why i still having issue.
in you answer output is right but when i apply in my code it still return 0.3999999999999999

Comment: ok done. thanks
sorry i made dumb mistake in my code.

Comment: If you want to know exaclty why javascript isn't accurate you can go to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439981/5686835) or directly to the link that answer refers to [link](http://floating-point-gui.de/)